# Error with bindParam overwriting in PHP

Tags: php, pdo

This is a bit of a weird one, and I could well be coding this completely wrong - hence why I've hit the same error twice in two days, in completely different parts of a script. The code I'm using is below:

```
    public function findAll( $constraints = array() ) {

        // Select all records
        $SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this->tableName;

        // See if there's any constraints
        if( count( $constraints ) > 0 ) {
            $SQL .= ' WHERE ';

            foreach( $constraints as $field => $value ) {
                $SQL .= $field . ' = :' . $field . ' AND ';
            }

        }

        // Remove the final AND and prepare the statement
        $SQL = substr( $SQL, 0, -5 );       
        $PDOStatement = $this->PDO->prepare( $SQL );

        // Loop through constraints and bind parameters
        foreach( $constraints as $field => $value ) {
            print 'Binding ' . $field . ' to ' . $value . ' 
';
            $PDOStatement->bindParam( $field, $value );
        }

        $PDOStatement->execute();
        var_dump($PDOStatement);        

        while ( $results = $PDOStatement->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {

            var_dump($results);

        }

    }
```

I'm pretty new to using PDO, but basically I'm attempting to pass an array of constraints e.g.

```
array( 'active' => 1, 'name' => 'James' )
```

and return all rows from the table

```
WHERE active = 1 AND name = 'James'
```

If I use this array, the SQL executed from the first

```
var_dump( )
```

is

```
SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE active = :active AND name = 'James'
```

- exactly as I expect. The bound parameters prints 'Binding active to 1' and 'Binding name to James' - exactly as expected. The rows exist in the database, and yet the second

```
var_dump()
```

call for $results outputs nothing - i.e. no rows are returned.

If I pass an array of a single constraint, e.g.

```
array( 'active' => 1 )
```

, this works perfectly fine. It appears to be whenever multiple constraints are passed that it stops working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because [`bindParam`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) works by binding to a variable, and you are re-using the variable (`$value`) for multiple values. Try with [`bindValue`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead.

Or even better yet; Pass the values as an array to [`execute`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) instead. This makes the statement stateless, which is generally a good thing in programming.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, using [`bindValue`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead of [`bindParam`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) will certainly accomplish this. However, after spending a considerable amount of time troubleshooting this issue recently, I discovered an alternate solution. Here is how to accomplish PDO variable binding in a foreach loop using bindParam:

Replace the following line from the original post:

```
$PDOStatement->bindParam( $field, $value );
```

...with this:

```
$PDOStatement->bindParam( $field, $constraints[$field] );
```

Instead of binding `$value`, use `$array_name[$array_key]`. This works is because you are now binding to a unique variable instead of one that gets reused on each pass of the loop.

The variable `$field` used as the placeholder apparently does not need to be a unique variable, however. I have not thoroughly researched this yet, but a variable used as a placeholder appears to be parsed immediately (instead of being assigned as a variable reference) even when bindParam is used.

Also, as you would no longer need to access `$value` directly, you could also replace this:

```
foreach( $constraints as $field => $value ) {
```

... with this:

```
foreach (array_keys($constraints) as $field) {
```

This is optional, as it will work fine without this change. It looks cleaner in my opinion though, since it might get confusing later as to why `$value` is assigned but never used.