# Php PDO multiple prepare statements in transaction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code:

```
    $this->db->beginTransaction();
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES (NULL,:a,:b,NULL,NOW())';
    $sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
    foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
      $sth->bindParam(':' . $k, $v, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }

    $this->executeQueryRollbackOnException($sth, 'Message_1');
    $resetId = $this->db->lastInsertId();

    $query = 'UPDATE `table2` SET c=:c,d=:d WHERE reset_id IS NULL';
    $sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
    foreach ($values2 as $k => $v) {
      $sth->bindParam(':' . $k, $v, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }


    $this->executeQueryRollbackOnException($sth, 'Message_2');

    Zend_Debug::dump($sth->rowCount(), 'Affected'); // This is 0

    // Commit
    $this->db->commit();
```

...

```
  private function executeQueryRollbackOnException($sth, $message) {
    try {
      $sth->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $this->logSQLError($e);
      $this->db->rollBack();
      throw new Exception($message);
    }
  }
```

First query is executed but the second is not. No mysql error produced. Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe it is executed, but it doesn't match any row?

Comment: @KingCrunch No, I run it manually and it matches the associate rows

Comment: @dotoree By "Run it manually" you mean, that you _definitely_ know what `$k` and `$v` contains in each iteration and that a possible cast doesn't result in an unexpected value, that may lead to a query, that you don't expect (means: A query, that does _not_ match anything)?

Comment: @KingCrunch No, query matches I have test it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error with bindParam overwriting in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146897/error-with-bindparam-overwriting-in-php)

Comment: Off topic: it would be cleaner to wrap the try block around the sequence of queries, rather than using a separate method. For one thing, it makes it a little clearer when reading the sequence that the following queries won't be run.

Comment: @outis Yeah, I quess it would be. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
   $sth->bindParam(':' . $k, $v, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
```

Should be

```
foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
   $sth->bindParam(':' . $k, $values[$k], PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
```

Sorry I didn't posted the right code at first time, I excluded foreaches to simplify the code

Comment: In such a `foreach`-construct `$array[$key]` and `$value` is the same. Sure, that this is a solution?

Comment: @KingCrunch I am Sure. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146897/error-with-bindparam-overwriting-in-php

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using `bindParam` over `bindValue`. With latter, `$v` should work as well. The problem is you're storing a reference with `bindParam`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `$sth->rowCount()` is 0 does not mean the query was not run.  If you have no error reported in your PHP error log, then the query ran just fine.  If the row count is 0, that means that no rows were updated.  This is very likely due to your condition not matching any rows.

Run the following; if you get 0, then you know the problem is your `UPDATE` condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table2` WHERE reset_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanx but the problem was in foreach, see my answer